# Base Href not working in internal routes Angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have this path/folder in my server: `site.com/products`

and I'm trying to deploy my Angular 12 app into this folder by FTP.

Currently, I'm doing the build like this: `ng build --prod --base-href=/products/`, and when I deploy all the files in the dist folder, only the main page is working.

When I try to click on any main page link, it sends me to a URL with the base href:

```
<a href="categoria/{{cat.jerarquia}}">Link</a>

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'categoria/:id', component: CategoriaComponent },
  { path: 'producto/:id', component: ProductoComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

How can I make work the base URL that I do in the ng build through all routes all my app ?

Comment: What do your routerLinks look like?

Comment: Wait.. you’re using hrefs for your links..?

Comment: Anyway, don’t start your links (hrefs or routerLink) with a slash. It will nullify your base href.

Comment: ok, I got it, I removed the initial slash and it sends to the right URL ,but it shows me 404 error and it shouldn't happen..

Comment: Nevermind, in the end all it works with routerlinks instead of href.. thanks